# PHP class error in incluiding file

Tags: php

I try to include a file and want to use a function from a other included file but i become this error

> Call to a member function test() on null

this code works fine: 
index.php

```
<?php 

include("Framework/ini.php");
$test = new testclass;
$test->x = 1;

$test->test();

?>
```

ini.php

```
<?php 

class testclass {

    public $x = 0;

    function test(){

        return $this->x;

    }

}

?>
```

index2.php

```
<?php 

echo $test->test();

?>
```

but if i include the file over the class i become the error
index.php

```
<?php 

 include("Framework/ini.php");
 $test = new testclass;
 $test->x = 1;

 $test->test();

 ?>
```

ini.php

```
<?php 

class testclass {

    public $x = 0;

    function test(){

        require_once("folder/index2.php");

    }

}

?>
```

i want to include the file over the class. how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: $test = new testclass();  maybe?

Comment: Did you try to use absolute filesystem path in the include? i.e `include('/home/path/to/ini.php')`

Comment: Read about Autoloading in php!

Comment: Perhaps it's just for the anonymised names but I have terrible difficulties trying to grasp your intentions (I don't think you're trying to create an infinite loop). Whatever, don't even try. The whole point of OOP is having maintainable code. Class instances that pop up randomly don't help at all. Pass stuff as parameters.

Comment: Note: The `require_once` in the method is most understandable part. Why at this point? Thing you have to understnad more how php works and how includes work, also namespaes and autoloader and so on..

Comment: or `include(__DIR__.'/Framwork/ini.php')`